# How to use my Cookie class properly

Tags: php, cookies

I just started with OOP programming in PHP and I have made a cookie class.

With doing that i have got a few questions unanswered

- is my class correct?
- how do I use it properly in my page? ( lets think i want to see how many times the visitor visited my website before and output the result for the user )

I already tested it after loging in and using this code:

```
$cookie = new Cookie();
$cookie->store();
print_r($_COOKIE);
```

(I had a result thrown back but I don't know if its the good result)
Bellow you can find my Cookie class.

```
<?php
class Cookie {
    /* cookie $id */ 
    private $id = false;

    /* cookie life $time */
    private $time = false;

    /* cookie $domain */
    private $domain = false;    

    /* cookie $path */
    private $path = false;

    /* cookie $secure (true is https only) */
    private $secure = false;


    public function __construct ($id, $time = 3600, $path = false, $domain = false, $secure = false) {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->time = $time;                  
        $this->path = $path;
        $this->domain = $domain;      
        $this->secure = $secure;
    }

    public function store() {
        foreach ($this->parameters as $parameter => $validator) {
            setcookie($this->id . "[" . $parameter . "]", $validator->getValue(), time() + $this->time, $this->path, $this->domain, $this->secure, true);        
        }            
    }     

    public function restore() {
        if (isset($_COOKIE[$this->id])) {

            foreach ($_COOKIE[$this->id] as $parameter => $value) {
                $this->{$parameter} = $value;
            }
        }   
    }           

    public function destroy() {
        $this->time =  -1;
    }   
}
?>
```

I hope someone can give me a good example! thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Where do you get `$this->parameters` in `public function store()` and `public function restore()` ? I don't see it defined anywhere in the class?

Comment: Also are you planing to have one instance of this class for all cookies or you'll have a new instance of this class for every cookie?

Comment: we'll i am not sure i made this class with some help of several websites. and i tought it was a PHP property that did not needed to be defined. but now i look at this again and again i think the class is not gonna work in ages like this!

Comment: In first instance i wanted a new instance of this class for every cookie. but i did not know how to create a good one so i tought maybe to start with one instance of the class.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This code should do the most frequent tasks you'll need to manipulate cookies.
Don't get confused by reading the getter and setter methods - they're used to access the private variables defined in the class. 
Have in mind this class is used per cookie and you need to have a new instance for every new cookie you'll operate over.
Below the class I've added an example how to use the class.

```
<?php
/**
 * Cookie manager.
 */
class Cookie
{
    /**
     * Cookie name - the name of the cookie.
     * @var bool
     */
    private $name = false;

    /**
     * Cookie value
     * @var string
     */
    private $value = "";

    /**
     * Cookie life time
     * @var DateTime
     */
    private $time;

    /**
     * Cookie domain
     * @var bool
     */
    private $domain = false;

    /**
     * Cookie path
     * @var bool
     */
    private $path = false;

    /**
     * Cookie secure
     * @var bool
     */
    private $secure = false;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct() { }

    /**
     * Create or Update cookie.
     */
    public function create() {
        return setcookie($this->name, $this->getValue(), $this->getTime(), $this->getPath(), $this->getDomain(), $this->getSecure(), true);
    }

    /**
     * Return a cookie
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function get(){
        return $_COOKIE[$this->getName()];
    }

    /**
     * Delete cookie.
     * @return bool
     */
    public function delete(){
        return setcookie($this->name, '', time() - 3600, $this->getPath(), $this->getDomain(), $this->getSecure(), true);
    }


    /**
     * @param $domain
     */
    public function setDomain($domain) {
        $this->domain = $domain;
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getDomain() {
        return $this->domain;
    }

    /**
     * @param $id
     */
    public function setName($id) {
        $this->name = $id;
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @param $path
     */
    public function setPath($path) {
        $this->path = $path;
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getPath() {
        return $this->path;
    }

    /**
     * @param $secure
     */
    public function setSecure($secure) {
        $this->secure = $secure;
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getSecure() {
        return $this->secure;
    }

    /**
     * @param $time
     */
    public function setTime($time) {
        // Create a date
        $date = new DateTime();
        // Modify it (+1hours; +1days; +20years; -2days etc)
        $date->modify($time);
        // Store the date in UNIX timestamp.
        $this->time = $date->getTimestamp();
    }

    /**
     * @return bool|int
     */
    public function getTime() {
        return $this->time;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $value
     */
    public function setValue($value) {
        $this->value = $value;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getValue() {
        return $this->value;
    }
}

/**
 * Create a cookie with the name "myCookieName" and value "testing cookie value"
 */
$cookie = new Cookie();
// Set cookie name
$cookie->setName('myCookieName');
// Set cookie value
$cookie->setValue("testing cookie value");
// Set cookie expiration time
$cookie->setTime("+1 hour");
// Create the cookie
$cookie->create();
// Get the cookie value.
print_r($cookie->get());
// Delete the cookie.
//$cookie->delete();

?>
```

P.S. I've commented the `$cookie->delete();` on purpose so that you can see the content of `print_r($cookie->get())`.

Edit:
Question: Where does the code go to see if the cookie is set?
Answer: 
You should check what does $_COOKIE do in the [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php). 
Basically the server sends headers to the client's browser which stores the cookies on the client's computer. When the client initializes a connection to the server it passes the cookies with the request.

Question: Where goes the $cookie->delete();
Answer:
There isn't a direct way to delete cookies. So in order to do that you need to create a cookie with the same name and expiration time which is in the past. When you do that the cookie is removed from the client's browser.

Comment: thanks for sharing this! i really appreciate it.

but i got some little questions about it after testing. where does the code go to see if the cookie is set? 

where goes the $cookie->delete(); if i use it in a login form for example?

Comment: You're welcome. If you find it useful and you think this is the answer to your question please mark my answer as the correct one. Cheers :)

Comment: ha can you help me with the 2 little questions above also?

Comment: where does the code go to see if the cookie is set?(example a admin page or so) where goes the $cookie->delete(); if i use it in a login form for example?

Comment: i got a nice solution for the first one! thanks alot! and for the delete i don;t really got a answer yet butt i hope i find that solution soon!

Comment: Sorry if I didn't give you the answer you needed. 
About the `delete` and in general about cookies - you need to set them before you send the headers or they'll not work. It doesn't matter where exactly you set them as long as it's before you send the headers.

Comment: FYI - You have $name as a bool instead of a string